# oracle - odp.net. When is the connection in the pool is released?

Tags: .net, oracle

I connect to SQL Oracle with connection string like this:

```
Data Source=xx;Password=xx;User ID=xx;Connection Lifetime=120;Connection Timeout=180;Max Pool Size=1000;Incr Pool Size=5;Decr Pool Size=2;Statement Cache Size=1
```

But I dont't know when connection in the pool can be release. when connection has idle long time,is't it.

Answer (score 0):

Pool close free connection every 3 mins. Detail as below
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT164 (using a connection pool.)